# Why do I fail to `diff` over `ssh`?

Tags: macos, bash, ssh

**Problem**

Following [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/59140/how-do-diff-over-ssh) I tried to use `diff` over `ssh` using bash process substitution

```
 diff foo <(ssh myServer 'cat foo')
```

When I enter the following command

```
diff /Volumes/MyBook/Remi/SimulationsOutputs/Hermes/C_no_F/C_no_F_allele_005.txt  <(ssh matthey@bugaboo.westgrid.ca 'cat /home/matthey/scratch/Plasticity/outputs/C_no_F/C_no_F_allele_005.txt')
```

, I am asked to enter my password (as expected) by the following prompt

```
matthey@bugaboo.westgrid.ca's password:
```

But whatever I write is displayed on the following line! If I press enter, then nothing happens.

**Extra-info**

`diff` seems to work fine when comparing local files

`ssh` seems to work fine

After double checking 25 times, I can say that the files exist and that I know the password!

I am on Mac OSX 10.11.2

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is generate a private/public key pair on your PC, copy the public key to the server and then connect. This can be done by running `ssh-keygen -t rsa` on your local machine. Output will be similar to below:

```
td512@kettecomp2:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/td512/.ssh/id_rsa):
Created directory '/home/td512/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/td512/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/td512/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
f9:cd:fe:c1:77:90:40:34:9c:34:cb:f6:2c:cc:32:6a td512@kettecomp2
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|           +*.   |
|           oo+   |
|            =    |
|         . + + . |
|        S o + =  |
|         o = o . |
|        E . o o o|
|       .   .   o.|
|            ...  |
+-----------------+
td512@kettecomp2:~$
```

After this, you need to copy the public key to the server. My favorite way is to open the ssh public key in textedit and copy it. The key can be found at `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` where `~` signifies your home directory.

Once copied to your clipboard, ssh to the server and run this command (beware not to copy + paste, as you already have the public key in your clipboard):

`cd && mkdir .ssh && chmod 700 .ssh && touch .ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys && nano .ssh/autorized_keys`

The above code will create the required directory and file, then make them have the right permissions. after which, you should have `nano` open. Paste your public key, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> say yes at the prompts and then log out of ssh.

The next part is to implement your code. This can be done like this:

`diff foo <(ssh myServer -l user -i .ssh/id_rsa 'cat foo')` where `user` is your username for the server and `.ssh/id_rsa` is your private key. This should stop the password prompts.

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is caused by the password prompt? Can you explain why? That's a weird problem, I'm curious what's causing it.

Comment: @gronostaj he says in the OP `matthey@bugaboo.westgrid.ca's password:` the SSH key method means no password prompt, since server + client negotiate automatically

Comment: @gronostaj it's just to bypass the password prompt and let ssh do it's job

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, that's not my question. Regular SSH-ing with password works just fine unless you try to redirect its output, input and output streams are working. Why would output redirection work with keys, but not with password?

Comment: @gronostaj I'm not sure. All I know is that it works...

Answer (score 0):

This way `diff` command doesn't consume input instead of `ssh` if that is the problem.

```
ssh myServer 'cat foo' | diff foo -
```